# Error in formula with predefined variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, excel-formula

I want to add a formula for this range inside my macro and include inside it the variable percentage that I have set in the beginning of the macro. When I run it, it says there is an error "Application or object defined error" in this line. The entire macros runs perfectly, but today I want to add this line and it wont, so obviously the error is in the syntax of the formula. I am providing it below.

```
ws3.Range("C9:C12").Formula = "=IFERROR(B9/(1- & percentage),"""")"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything inside the quotes will appear as a literal string so you will get the word "percentage" appearing in your formula. The spreadsheet doesn't know what this is as you have defined it in your macro (there is no doubt a proper technical term for this).

Amended as per @Peh's suggestion.

```
ws3.Range("C9:C12").Formula = "=IFERROR(B9/(" & 1-percentage & "),"""")"
```

Comment: alternatively use `ws3.Range("C9:C12").Formula = "=IFERROR(B9/" & 1 - percentage & ","""")"` so the calculation `1-percentage` is done only once in VBA instead of every recalculation in Excel cells (which is faster).